# Windows Containers - culture settings

Tags: windows, docker, containers, culture

I need to run a legacy application on my computer, which requires a specific culture setting in Windows in order to work. I do not want to change the global culture settings in Windows in order to accommodate this application

I could run it in a Virtual Machine, but I would prefer to run it in a Docker Windows Container instead, if possible.

Is it possible to configure a specific culture for an application running in a Docker Windows Container, and how is this done?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft publishes tags for base images for all the supported cultures: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/tags/

So I think you can just base yourself on the culture that you want.

In addition, have you tried `Set-Culture`?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/international/set-culture

Comment: It seems they have stopped providing culture specific base images after build 10.0.14393

Comment: I tried set-culture in the dockerfile but its not change the culture.

Answer (score 3):

There is a working trick for this problem:

```
docker run --name temp-container --user "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" --isolation=process your-image:your-tag powershell Set-Culture en-AU

docker commit temp-container your-image:your-tag
docker rm temp-container
```

Now you can start your image:

```
docker run --rm -it --isolation=process your-image:your-tag powershell
```

And you will have culture 'en-AU'